# dropdown not populating after ajax call in mvc5 platform

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5

Have a good day. I here because of I am suffering a problem. That is I am working with a cascade dropdown in a user controller. When I change the MotherCompany then Division will appear as per mothercompany. My Controller end code is working fine. But in Front End Dropdown is not populating. What I am doing wrong can Anybody help me please. ( Sorry for my BAD English )

controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult getDivision(int id)
        {
            var division = db.Divisions.Where(x => x.MotherCompanyId == id).ToList();
            List<SelectListItem> listDivision = new List<SelectListItem>();

            listDivision.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select State--", Value = "0" });
            if (division != null)
            {
                foreach (var x in division)
                {
                    listDivision.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id.ToString() });

                }
            }
            return Json(new SelectList(listDivision, "Value", "Text"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
My Javascript here:
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#MotherCompanyId").change(function () {
            $("#divisionId").empty();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("getDivision")',
                async: true,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { id: $("#MotherCompanyId").val() },
                success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                        $('select#divisionId').append(
                            $("<option></option>")
                                .attr("Value", val.Value)
                                .text(val.Text));
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(" An error occurred.");
                },
            });
            return false;
        })
    });
```

View: `

```
<div class="form-group MotherCompanyId">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MotherCompanyId, new { @class = "" })
                                @Html.DropDownList("MotherCompanyId", ViewBag.MotherCompanyId as SelectList, "Select a MotherCompany", htmlAttributes: new { required = "required", style = "display:none;width:100%;" })
                                @Html.StarkDropDownAjaxLink("/MotherCompany/Create", "AddMore", "")
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group DivisionId">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DivisionId, new { @class = "" })
                                @Html.DropDownList("divisionId", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "--Select Division--", new { style = "display:none;width:100%;" })
                                @Html.StarkDropDownAjaxLink("/Division/Create", "AddMore", "")
                            </div>`
```

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow. Does it give you any error on the console? What is the value of the data after success?

Comment: I can read the json data on network when I go to browser console